# How do I work with large data streams in python?

Tags: python

Python noob, strong c background.

I'm writing a simple server that reads blocks of size 1024 bytes from a socket. I need to concatenate the blocks into one large file (it's a video).  For starters I have tried something like this

```
movie = bytearray()
while numblocksrxd != numBlocks:
    data=conn.recv(1024)
    numblocksrxd+=1
    movie = movie+data
```

I've quickly realized that this code creates a new instance of `movie` each time I assign to it, which results in increasingly larger mem copies as it grows (I think).  If I were doing this in C I'd simply malloc the space I needed and fill it in as it came.  How would I handle this in python?

Comment: Just dump the data to the file as you receive it unless there is some specific reason to keep humongous amount of data in memory.

Comment: True, that was my fallback plan.  The file size will be somewhere on the order of a few mb so it should be easy enough to keep it in memory. I guess I'm wondering about this more as a conceptual problem than practical.

Comment: Well if you want to store it in memory you can, but it will take the couple MB + most likely some extra for overhead. Big difference is that in python you don't need to do anything special in order to achieve that, just append the incoming stream to a string (or other structure that fits you data best) and python will take care of memory allocation.

Comment: As a side note, you don't need to write looks like `numblocksrxd = 0` … `while numblocksrxd != numBlocks:` … `numblocksrxd += 1`; just do `for numblocksrxd in range(numBlocks):`

Comment: Thank you abarnert these are the kinds of things I need to learn!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
movie += data
```

Augmented assignments are generally done without creating a new object if their target is mutable. In this case, `bytearray` supports in-place `+=`, so this code won't create a new object. When the bytearray's internal buffer runs out of room, it'll allocate a new one, but the allocation takes amortized constant time and the `movie` object managing the buffer won't be replaced.

Comment: Yeah, but this still reallocates and copies the array repeatedly, which is more expensive than the "creating a bytearray header" part.

Comment: @abarnert: I'm pretty sure it uses an intelligent resizing policy.

Comment: Yes, although before 2.5 or so it was still quadratic to append strings, and since then, it's not quadratic with `+=` but it's _also_ not quadratic with `+`. So, this isn't likely to make a big difference.

Comment: @abarnert: It's not a string, though. It's a bytearray.

Comment: Wow like magic this simple change fixed everything. With my code it was taking over 5 minutes to read and store about 10mb of data. With your change it only takes seconds.  Python is a strange language, though I hope I can master it one day.

Comment: '+=' has similar magic in other O-O languages as well, since it allows in-place update, vs the copy-and-reassign of 'x = x + y'.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you really need more efficiency than just appending onto a byte-string like this. Yes, it will reallocate the array and copy it, but it uses the usual exponential expansion tricks so the amortized time is still constant.

If you really need more efficiency (and I doubt you do, but…), you can just store a `list` of byte strings instead of one big one. If you can use that as-is, great. If not, you can concatenate them at the end with `join`. That's almost always the fastest way to build up a big string in Python. So:

```
movie = []
while numblocksrxd != numBlocks:
    data=conn.recv(1024)
    numblocksrxd+=1
    movie.append(data)
movie = b''.join(movie)
```

Or you can, of course, also use the same trick you'd use in C:

```
movie = bytearray(numBlocks * 1024)
while numblocksrxd != numBlocks:
    data=conn.recv(1024)
    numblocksrxd+=1
    movie[numblocksrxd*1024:(numblocksrxd+1)*1024] = data
```

Comment: I wish I could accept two answers as correct because this seems like a great solution as well. Thanks!